# Ajax code not getting executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

so im trying to delete data from a table via ajax. i found this tutorial online but when i click the delete button it just takes me to the top of the page instead of deleting my data. and it also throws a element not defined error in the console. Any help is gratefully accepted

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id,title,location,date,fb_page FROM gigs order by id desc ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error() . $sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['title'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['location'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['fb_page'].'</td>';
echo '<td> <div><a href=gigpic.php?id=' . $row['id'] . ' class="group1"><img class="img-responsive"  src=gigpic.php?id=' . $row['id'] . ' height="50%" width="50%"></a></div> </td>';
?>

 <td><a href="#" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="delbutton"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
 <div><a href="update_event.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="iframe" ><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a></div></td>
            <?php
            echo '</tr>';
            }
            ?>
```

my Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {

    $(".delbutton").click(function() {
        var del_id = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!")) {
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "delete_event.php",
                data : info,
                success : function() {
                }
            });
            $(this).parents(".record").animate({
                backgroundColor : "#fbc7c7"
            }, "fast").animate({
                opacity : "hide"
            }, "slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Well, so far I see a missing quote for `<a href=gigpic.php` - View HTML source.

Comment: `element` is defined somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

element is not defined is exactly what it says. You have a variable named element that you did not define.

```
var del_id = element.attr("id");
```

You probably meant to do this:

```
var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: Thanks Brian that worked. But can you tell me why doesn't it hide that particular row after its deleted.i have to keep refreshing the page to see the updated data

Comment: Because you are not telling it to. You can easily remove the row by putting $(this).parent().parent().remove(); inside the success function.